# Multiple Layers in Widget

Tags: c++, qt

I currently need a small ImageViewer in my project, where you can zoom in and go to next or previous image. These buttons should be fixed at right bottom corner like in this picture:

[image: Example picture with navigation buttons]

In this case I have q QLabel which has a Layout with some buttons. But now it should be zoomable, so I need QScrollArea, like explained [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-imageviewer-example.html). But how I add my buttons again in this example? It is possible to archive this view just with QtDesigner?

Comment: You can add the QLabel to the QScrollArea as viewport widget

Comment: Sure, that is the clear point. But where to add the buttons? If they are childs of QScrollarea they will be scrolled too

Comment: I got your point. See this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#stackUnder . I guess you can set the buttons and scroll area to be both children to a container widget, then stack scroll area under buttons.

Comment: Had hoped there is a better way, because on this I need to handle resize event always by myself. Btw: stackUnder is not necessary, if I had to add widgets on my own (last added is most top) .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [QToolBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html) will suite your needs. It will make a floating panel over your graphics view. An [example](http://apiexamples.com/cpp/QtWidgets/QToolBar.html). If you need to achieve the background of the toolbar transparent while its buttons are semi-transparent then it is doable as well. But first you need to decide if toolbar works for you.

Comment: If I set "background : rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);" on QToolBar it isn't partially transparent (tested by preview in QDesigner)